# Is there a way to prevent input if today's date is the same or later than the date in an adjacent cell?

Tags: validation, google-sheets

Using Google Sheets, is there a way to prevent a user from adding contents to a cell or changing the contents if today's date is the same or later than the date in an adjacent cell?

For example:

[image: Example]

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest using data validation. Set your range (eg: Sheet1!B1:B), choose 'custom formula' from the dropdown and use this formula

```
=today()>$A1
```

Then select 'Refuse input' when invalid data is entered.
Another possible solution would be to use Google Script.

I hope this helps?

Comment: Thanks for your help. That works great for empty cells that I want to keep empty. The problem is that I want to apply it to cells with contents so that they can’t be changed. Maybe I’m doing it wrong.